# Create a new answer for release-specific solution or add to existing (and selected answer)?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do we do about topics spanning multiple versions of Ubuntu?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1828/what-do-we-do-about-topics-spanning-multiple-versions-of-ubuntu)

For release-specific solutions two approaches are being taken: either edited into existing, and selected answer, or a separate answer entirely.

Personally, I think it should be edited into an existing answer. But there are a few issues like the original author having a different solution in mind, and the one updating it not getting the credit (reputation) for it, etc.

On the other hand, separating release-specific solution doesn't bring it the attention of a selected answer to it. Same thing happens if the new release-specific answer is selected as the correct solution.

An ideal solution would be an AU-specific feature that lets us manage release-specific answers (I've some ideas in mind, but this is not the post for that), but for now we need to decide on standard practices for updating answers.